# Page-global keyboard events in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, keyboard-events

I'm working on a game, a Windows Store App based on WPF and written in C#. When the player presses the Esc key, I want to pause the game and show a menu (Continue, Quit etc.).

Sounds simple. Sadly, it's not.

The game takes place in a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page` and primarily consists of hundreds of `Shape`s in a `Canvas`, but no single `Button`, `TextBox` or anything else that supports keyboard interaction. The only interaction is clicking or tapping shapes.

I need to catch keyboard events, globally for the whole page, no matter what element has the focus or if there even is any focus at all etc. Whenever the Esc key is pressed, an event has to fire.

What I tried:

- Using the event `Page.KeyDown` or overriding `Page.OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)` (or KeyUp): Does not fire, unless there is an element such as a `TextBox` with keyboard focus. But in my UI there is no such element.
- Using an invisible (`Opacity = 0` and/or hidden under the Canvas) TextBox as a hack to make KeyDown work: As soon as the Canvas or any Shape is clicked/tapped, the TextBox loses focus and the hack stops working. So, more hacks are needed to make it keep the focus, which screws with other things such as the menu buttons. Futhermore, the TextBox occasionally shows the Windows software keyboard, which is rather unwanted. A barely working, fragile hack.
- Using `InputGestures`, `KeyBinding` etc.: Not available for Windows Store Apps.

Any ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using [CoreWindow.KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keydown). Assign the handler in your page and I believe it should intercept all keydown events.

```
public MyPage()
{
    CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += MyPage_KeyDown;
}

void MyPage_KeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(args.VirtualKey.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks. I will do some more testing tomorrow and then accept your answer.

Comment: @keyboardP you saved my day!! No words to thank you... :-)

Answer (score 5):

CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown will not capture events if it the focus is on some other grid/webView/text box, so instead use *[AcceleratorKeyActivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.acceleratorkeyactivated)* event. Irrespective of where the focus is it will always capture the event.

```
public MyPage()
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += AcceleratorKeyActivated;
}


private void AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.EventType.ToString().Contains("Down"))
    {
        var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
        if (ctrl.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down))
        {
            switch (args.VirtualKey)
            {
                case VirtualKey.A:
                    Debug.WriteLine(args.VirtualKey);
                    Play_click(sender, new RoutedEventArgs());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```