# Capture Esc Key in UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to create a `Custom Popup` using `UserControl`, because this is `UWP` apps, I want to hide `Popup` when user press `ESC` on Keyboard.

I try to override `OnKeyDown` method of `UserControl` but this method never executed when I press `ESC` on Keyboard.

```
 protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Escape)
    {
       this.Visibility = Visibility.Colapse;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You could try `PreviewKeyDown` event

Comment: i  am not confident uwp, but i know winform, with winform you have to activate key preview (set that property to true, on the form of your interest) in order to get KeyDown work properly in you UC.
May be the same thing in your scenario ?

Comment: I have checked, UWP doesn't have `PreviewKeyDown` method or key preview like in Windows Form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792978/page-global-keyboard-events-in-windows-store-apps) as I guess it's not possible to do this via a User Control. Did you try `OnKeyDown` when the control was focussed, by the way? The solution should be to either catch the ESC key globally for the whole window or inside a TextBox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to hide Popup when user press ESC on Keyboard.

In UWP app, consider using [CoreWindow.CharacterReceived event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx)

In UserControl, add event handler in the Constructor method:

```
public CustomPopupControl()
{
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += CoreWindow_CharacterReceived;
}

private void CoreWindow_CharacterReceived(CoreWindow sender, CharacterReceivedEventArgs args)
{
            if(args.KeyCode==27) //ESC
            {
        //Do somthing
                this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
}
```