# Caps Lock Detection - Windows 10 vs Windows 10 Mobile - C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, capslock

I need to detect if the CapsLock Key is Locked (active) or not, but when I try this:

```
public void CapsLockStatus()
{
    if ((CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.CapitalLock) &
        CoreVirtualKeyStates.Locked) != 0)
    {
         //true -> Caps Lock is enable;
    }
    else
    {
        //false -> Caps Lock is disable;
    }
}
```

In Windows 10 Desktop, it works fine, but in Windows 10 mobile it does not.
I try to replace `"GetKeyState"` with `"GetAsyncKeyState"` but the problem still remains.

What's the problem? Someone Help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> This code, in Windows 10 Desktop, are fine, work perfectly, but in widows 10 mobile not

Actually, there is no CapsLock Key in the Virtual Keyboard in Windows 10 Mobile OS, if we need to ensure inputting uppercase letter, just pressing the Shirt key twice. So you can't detect it in this scenario.

[image]

The next question is, why do you need to detect the CapsLock Key in UWP mobile app? The only possible scenario is for password inputting and remindering user, but as we know, **the user experience on Mobile is different with the one on PC**, if an user press the Shift key twice, he/her will notice this change because the virtual keyboard has occupied lots of the screen space.

If you really need to do this, consider using [CoreWindow.CharacterReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx) event to detect the current KeyCode to check if the user has typed a uppercase letter. See [my answer in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371280/capture-esc-key-in-usercontrol/34380745#34380745)

Comment: Chen, Thanks for fast reply. 
I use the "KeyDown" event instead "CharaterReceived" because, the Charater Receiver fired only when input data in element, and I need to detect key is locked or not, regardless of whether there is any element with focus.

Thanks