# (UWP) Using ESC Key to Close ModalDialog

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, template10

I'm displaying `ModalDialog` using sample code `Busy.xaml` in `Template10` :

```
    public static void SetBusy(bool busy, string text = null)
    {
        WindowWrapper.Current().Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
        {
            var modal = Window.Current.Content as ModalDialog;
            var view = modal.ModalContent as Busy;
            if (view == null)
                modal.ModalContent = view = new Busy();
            modal.IsModal = view.IsBusy = busy;
            view.BusyText = text;
            modal.CanBackButtonDismiss = true;
        });
    }
```

I can close this dialog by using `ALT+Left Arrow`, but on most Desktop application pressing `ESC` key usually will also close popup or dialog.

I try to add code to handle `KeyDown` on `Busy.xaml` but this method never executed when I press `ESC` or any key.

```
     private void UserControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Escape)
         {
             e.Handled = true;
             SetBusy(false);
         }
     }
```

So, how to make this `ModalDialog` close when user press `ESC` key ?

Comment: I have edited my question, thanks.

Comment: @AskTooMuch Note to your use-case: beside handling "escape" on the keyboard, you might want to handle the "B" button on XBox controllers, as well as the "hardware back button" on mobile devices like phones and tablets.

Comment: I have tested, most of those scenario has been handled by Template10, I cannot confirm if it's handle "B" button on XBOX since I don't have XBOX device to test, but thanks to let me know this issue.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371280/capture-esc-key-in-usercontrol) post too. It seems an easier solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to attach an event handler to the `CharacterReceived` event of the `CoreWindow`.

Modify the `SetBusy` method:

```
public static void SetBusy(bool busy, string text = null)
{
    WindowWrapper.Current().Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
    {
        var modal = Window.Current.Content as ModalDialog;
        var view = modal.ModalContent as Busy;
        if (view == null)
            modal.ModalContent = view = new Busy();
        modal.IsModal = view.IsBusy = busy;
        view.BusyText = text;
        modal.CanBackButtonDismiss = true;

        // Attach to key inputs event
        var coreWindow = Window.Current.CoreWindow;
        coreWindow.CharacterReceived += CoreWindow_CharacterReceived;
    });
}
```

Where as the `CoreWindow_CharacterReceived` would look like this:

```
private static void CoreWindow_CharacterReceived(CoreWindow sender,
                                                 CharacterReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    // KeyCode 27 = Escape key
    if (args.KeyCode != 27) return;

    // Detatch from key inputs event
    var coreWindow = Window.Current.CoreWindow;
    coreWindow.CharacterReceived -= CoreWindow_CharacterReceived;

    // TODO: Go back, close window, confirm, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the modal is open just use something along this route:

```
private void Modal_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Another way to address `(e.KeyCode==Keys.Escape)` is:

```
(e.KeyChar == (char)27)
```

or

```
e.KeyCode==(char)Keys.Escape
```

For this code to work, you need `Form.KeyPreview = true;`

For more information on what's above: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx

I believe that you need to append the [`CancelButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx) Property for this to work properly.

(Almost the same approach) I believe this should work nicely as well:

```
private void HandleEsc(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        Close();
}
```

This is for a console application:

```
if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have try this but doesn't work (see my updated question).

Comment: @AskTooMuch I've edited my answer, see if that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using UWP in Windows 10 and Template10 library, not Clasic Desktop app.